# FM or something like that to copy cofiles from one server to another

Tags: abap, transport, sap-basis

I'm developing an ABAP program to transport orders from one system to another (in a different landscape). To do that I need to copy the cofiles from the source system to the target system, so I can add the orders to the import queue. That copy can't be done manually, it has to be the program to do all that... copy the files from the source system to the target, add the orders to the import queue and transport them.

Any thoughts how I can do this within the program (only the part of copying the files between different systems)?

Comment: I suspect there is a strong reason for not using the TMS built-in capabilities...?

Comment: Are you sure you are talking about transferring orders? cofiles are part of the transport system so you wouldn't be creating transports for copying orders from 1 system to another I think.

Comment: I suppose he is wrong in terms. Either he use *orders* instead of *requests*, or he has no idea about TMS. Orders (POs, delivery) are transactional data, which is out of the scope of TMS.

Comment: Sorry, I really mean requests... I said orders because that's what we call it in portuguese, so I did a straight translation.
What I need to do is to transport a  request to a completely different SAP server (the two of the don't have a direct connection, they're not in the same environment), so I think I need to copy the cofiles to the target server, so I can insert the request to the import queue and them "transport" the request to the target server

Comment: @anfil89 I had the same problem in a Spanish speaking project. We also used "order" as a translation for "la orden" while it actually should have been "request". :)

Comment: Yeah, it's always a pain to translate "technical" names/expressions to other languages

Answer (score 0):

Seems impossible for me. Currently, the easiest way to transport program/object between different system is [abapGit](https://github.com/larshp/abapGit), but still some tasks are required on target system.

Comment: Thanks Michal...
However I've been thinking and I thought the possibility to create 2 RFC's, the first will run in the "source system" and reads the file and save it's content in an internal table using "OPEN DATASET", and returns it... and then another that run's in the "target system" (I'll pass the internal table from the other one as input) and does the opposite, reads the table into a file. Do you think this will work?

Comment: If You can call RFC from a target system to source system, I think this operation cloud be done.

Comment: @anfil89 If you have a physical connection between those systems then use TMS. Why do you want to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: I don't have a physical connection, they're separated systems, that's why I'm having troubble. But I think the 2 RFC solution is a valid way to do it. Thanks for the help